# Split single column values into multiple lines

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have list with single line of text with values separated by commas. I want to display those valuse in multiple lines.

```
Example: Stock (Column)
         Google;Microsoft;Apple;
```

Now I want to display them in separate lines.

```
Example: Google
         Microsoft
         Apple
```

Can any one please provide the solution.

Comment: Have you found a solution for your question?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

As you cannot really change the lookup column itself, I'd suggest to add to the page a script that will modify the view.

Here is a basic example written with jQuery:

```
$("td").find("a").each(function(){
    $(this).before("<br/>");
});
```

what it does is add a line break before each hyperlink.

Comment: Please let us know the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to convert the single line of text field to a multiline of text field set as plain text.  The users can put them on multiple lines and you don't have to worry about scripting or coding any custom displays.

Comment: I am sorry, it is a look up column not a single line of text. I appreciate your response

Comment: Then you might want to update the question to reflect what you're actually asking for.